# 'str' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django 3.8.1 I am building a chat app. AND i am stuck on an Error.

views.py

```
def chat(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.method.is_authenticated:
            chat_boxes = ChatBox.objects.filter(Q(user_1=request.user) | Q(user_2=request.user))
            groups = ChatGroup.objects.filter(members=request.user)
        else:
            chat_boxes = []
            groups = []
        return render(request, 'chathome.html', {'chat_boxes':chat_boxes,'groups':groups})

    else:
        form = ChatGroupForm(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES)
        group = form.save(commit=False)
        group.author = request.user
        group.save()
        group.members.add(request.user)
        group.group_admins.add(request.user)
        return redirect('profile',pk=group.id)
```

**The Problem**

When i open browser it is showing `'str' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'`

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thank You In Advance

Comment: You probably mean Python-3.8.5 , the latest release of Django is 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the *user* is authenticated, a method can not be authenticated, since that is just a string `'GET'`, `'POST`, etc.:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # …
```